# What Are Steps To Install MySQL?

Tags: installation, server, mysql

To my downloads directory, I have unpacked the `MySQL-server-5.6.11-2.linux_glibc2.5.i386.rpm`. There is now a `/usr` directory with `/bin`, `/lib`, `/sbin`, and `/share` within the /usr. There is also a `/etc` directory with `/init.d` and `/logrotate.d` directories within the /etc.

- Do I disperse these directories/files in the appropriate "/" root directory location(s)?
- Where can I find clear steps on how to install MySQL on Ubuntu? (I have version 13.04)

From the MySQL site, it seemed easier to do this for Windows since they are able to use the MySQL Installer.

Comment: which OS you are using ?

Comment: OS is Ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Installation**

To install MySQL, run the following command from a terminal prompt:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

During the installation process you will be prompted to enter a password for the MySQL root user.

Once the installation is complete, the MySQL server should be started automatically. You can run the following command from a terminal prompt to check whether the MySQL server is running:

```
sudo netstat -tap | grep mysql
```

When you run this command, you should see the following line or something similar:

> tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         *:*                LISTEN 
>   2556/mysqld

If the server is not running correctly, you can type the following command to start it:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

[**More info HERE**](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/mysql.html)

Comment: Excellent. That seems pretty clear and straightforward. Thank you penreturn.

Answer (score 1):

Forget this .rpm, it's for Red Hat/Fedora.

All you have to do is open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Or you can search for "mysql" in the Software Center.